# Getting Links from a Dynamic Webpage

Tags: selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to get all links from a JS-based dynamic webpage with a load more option. I think I trigger THE page to scroll down. But, I could not get all the links. It turns only 103 links. I need to fix my script to get all the links but I don't know where is the error.

Best,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = "https://www.mofa.gov.kw"
PAGE_URL = "https://www.mofa.gov.kw/en/media-center/news/"


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

unique_urls = set() 

with open("urls.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for page in range(1, 2500):  # can adjust this 
        page_params = {"page": page, "from": "None", "to": "None"}
        response = requests.get(PAGE_URL, params=page_params, headers=headers)

       
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f"Failed to access page {page}")
            continue

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        
        for link in soup.select("a[href^='/en/media-center/news/']"):
            full_url = BASE_URL + link.get('href')
            unique_urls.add(full_url)  

    
    for url in unique_urls:
        f.write(url + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate the button press with:

```
document.getElementById('load-more').click();
```

It seems like there could be thaousands of pages, so a loop makes sense to press the load more button for x-times(in this example 500). To give the webserver some time to respond, the button is pressed every 300ms.

```
let i = 0; 
const interval = setInterval(function() {
       document.getElementById('load-more').click();
i++ ;
if(i>= 500){clearInterval(interval)}
}, 300);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but your suggestion entails using selenium right? Is there a way to put your solution into my script above? Thank you so much.

Comment: The code is in js, therefore it cant be used directly in python. Im Sorry my solution wont work for you.

Comment: Maybe @MendelG might be interested in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe insert a wait, so the webserver think it isnt ddosed:

```
import time

time.sleep(0.5)
```

So in your case:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = "https://www.mofa.gov.kw"
PAGE_URL = "https://www.mofa.gov.kw/en/media-center/news/"


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

unique_urls = set() 

with open("urls.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for page in range(1, 2500):  # can adjust this 
        page_params = {"page": page, "from": "None", "to": "None"}
        response = requests.get(PAGE_URL, params=page_params, headers=headers)

       
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f"Failed to access page {page}")
            continue

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        
        for link in soup.select("a[href^='/en/media-center/news/']"):
            full_url = BASE_URL + link.get('href')
            unique_urls.add(full_url)  
        
        time.sleep(0.2)
    
    for url in unique_urls:
        f.write(url + "\n")
```

Comment: Dear Christian, thank you so much for this. It works well, but returns only 103 news link. This should be much more than this. I don't know why this is the case. I wrote another script and it reported that it loads pages 144 times, meaning that there should be 144*6 news link because each load includes 6 different news item.

Comment: Have you Tried increasing the wait time to something like 0.4 secs? I know that this is not optimale, because the runtime is increasing, but ther could be the possibility the server is overloaded by the requests.  Add a printout of the faulty request:  print(response.status_code)    maybe then, the source of the problem is visible.